Torus Quotient by action
I am stuck on understanding, what is the following quotient:
The group $\mathbb{Z}_2$ acts on $T^2$ by $(z,w)\mapsto (-\overline{z},-\overline{w})$ where the overline means the complex conjugate, is this still the two torus? Or did it change somehow?

What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

If you think about this action separeted then looks like that the quotient will be a product of two closed intervals because is a identification of circle under the reflexion around the y-axis in each factor, but I dont know if this is right,

The product of intervals would require that we could reflect in each coordinate separately.

I suggest adding what you tried to the post, so you can be helped to get a better answer. Don't want to give you stuff you already tried correct?

Is what still the two torus?

Let $I=[-1,1]$ with the quotient map $q:I\rightarrow S^1$ given by $q(s)=e^{\pi i s}$. Then your torus is a quotient of $I\times I$, and we're trying to find $X=(S^1\times S^1)/\mathbb{Z}_2$. The $\mathbb{Z}_2$ action you've defined acts on each coordinate as
\begin{equation*}
e^{\pi i s}\mapsto\begin{cases}
e^{\pi i(1-s)} & s\ge0\\
e^{\pi i(-1-s)} & s\le0
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
This defines an action up in $I\times I$ as well. Up there, for each coordinate, we have $\{\pm\tfrac{1}{2}\}$ is a fixed point, while negatives are sent to negatives and positives to positives. Specifically,
\begin{equation*}
(s,t)\mapsto \big(\mathrm{sgn}(s)-s,\mathrm{sgn}(t)-t\big)
\end{equation*}
[To keep things simple, let $\mathrm{sgn}(0)=1$; it doesn't matter since we will identify $1$ and $-1$ anyway in the end.]
We can now find a closed region within $I\times I$ that still maps onto $X$, and try and reason about the quotient structure of this region. The following picture shows this region shaded, and the colored points are examples of every $\mathbb{Z}_2$ orbit intersecting this region, so that it does indeed map surjectively to $X$.

Now there are identifications to make for this region: the top and bottom and middle horizontal edges because of the torus quotient and $\mathbb{Z}_2$ action, and some "foldings" on the vertical sides (top half and bottom half) because of the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ action. Let's divide the region into smaller rectangles, via the dashed horizontal lines, then label the edges for how they should be identified.

$D$, $E$, and $H$ are where we cut. $B$ is the top/bottom edge. The other edges are paired off based on the foldings of the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ action. Note that we actually want to identify $E$ and $B$, but they're labeled separately here. We can now glue the first two rectangles, and the last two rectangles separately, to get two hemispheres. For example, here's the top one:

We now identify $E$ and $B$ to get a $2$-sphere. We thus have two $2$-spheres (from the top two and bottom two rectangles), with a semicircular arc (coming from $E$) that needs to be identified. So our final space $X$ is these two $S^2$ glued along this arc.
